# CLR Profiler Error

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, profiler

im having a bit or trouble using the CLR profiler for windows mobile on one of my applications (for everything else it seems to work). I downloaded the profiler from the [.NET Compact Framework Power Toys 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13442).

The error I get when running the profiler is this:

> FlushLog failed. Error code:
>   0x80072714

The message is shown on the device in a mesasgebox. I tried googling the error but i couldnt seem to find any related information, i was hoping someone over here would have an idea what the error means?

Just to make it clear, the profiler seems to work for quite some time (during the startup of the application) but then suddenly stops and gives off the above error.

Thanks in Advance for any help!
Mike

Comment: It is a low-level networking error, WSAEINTR, "A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall".  Nothing you could easily fix I imagine, good profilers cost money.